# A boolean variable name suggestion

Tags: javascript

I have a Method name update, this will be called depending on the boolean variable.
I need suggestion how should I name this variable.

Comment: Maybe you could name it Steve. Or George.

Comment: @Joel Etherton, woah, flashback to Looney Toons **"I'm gonna love him, and hug him, and pet him, and call him George!"** -- Hugo the Abominable Snowman

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about `shouldUpdate`? Or describe the conditions under which it should update, e.g. `dirty`, `hasChanges` etc.

Comment: +1 for `dirty`, and `hasChanges`, but maybe that should be `isDirty`

Comment: I've always disliked `dirty` as a variable/method name, though I've no idea why.

Comment: I once saw in code a `dirty`, and then a `filthy` to indicate an advanced level of data "dirtiness"...

Comment: @Chad: I would write a property called isDirty(), but back it with a dirty variable, probably. "changes" is more ambiguous though, hence hasChanges.

Answer (score 1):

Well, "update" sounds like a bad method name.  What's it updating?

But, you could name it something like "shouldUpdate", "requiresUpdate", "needsUpdate"

Boolean variables should have a "question like" name.

Answer (score 0):

For a question with very little context you probably won't get much good input.

Since the variable is boolean the name should imply it's value is true/false, yes/no, etc...  so `shouldUpdate`, `needsSave`, `hasChanges`, `isModified` etc are all good.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know more about when `update` is called, but some possibilities are:

- `Dirty` - if the data changed, then update it
- `Stale` - if the data is stale, then update it :)